# accessing a hidden function with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Hi I have a few custom functions wrapped in jQuery's document.ready function. Most of these functions are utilized from within that function and work, but there is a case where I would like to access a function contained within this from the global scope. How can I do this? can i do something like:
      jQueryReadyScope.myFunctionName('paramaters');

Thank you very much.

Comment: First and foremost: Why do you want to access it? I'm not convinced that you need to access it from the outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, but you can name the function and pass it to `.ready()`:

```
var myFunctionName = function (params) {
   // do things
}

// pass as callback to ready function
jQuery(document).ready(myFunctionName);

// access directly like any other function:
myFunctionName('paramaters');
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Just attach some random object to the window-object like this: window["something"] = "else";

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I took the question to be: "can i do something like: `jQueryReadyScope.myFunctionName('paramaters');`". You can of course extend `window` like any other object.

Comment: I realized how you thought after a while though :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a scope issue, and all you need to do is specify the namespace. In this case, you're talking global so we'll use window.

```
window.myFunction = function() { ... stuff }
```

Answer (score 1):

To access it from the global scope it would need to be assigned to a global variable, either by declaring it outside your document ready or by assigning it as a property of `window`:

```
var yourGlobalFunction1 = function() { ... }

$(document).ready(function() {
    function privateFunction() { ... }

    window.yourGlobalFunction2 = function() { ... };

    yourGlobalFunction1();
    privateFunction();
    yourGlobalFunction2();
});

yourGlobalFunction1();

// and then at some later point AFTER the document ready has run,
// e.g., in response to some event:
$("#someelement").click(function() {
    yourGlobalFunction2();
});
```